# What is the meaning of the result of model.predict() function for semantic segmentation?

Tags: python, keras, predict, semantic-segmentation

I use [Segmentation Models](https://github.com/qubvel/segmentation_models) library for multi-class (in my case 4 class) semantic segmentation. The model (UNet with 'resnet34' backbone) is trained with 3000 RGB (224x224x3) images. The accuracy is around 92.80%.

1) Why model.predict() function requires (1,224,224,3) shaped array as input ? I didn't find the answer even in the [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/models/model/#predict). Actually, below code is working, I have no problem with it but I want to understand the reason.

```py
predictions = model.predict( test_image.reshape(-1,224,224,3) );
```

2) `predictions` is a (1,224,224,3) shaped numpy array. Its data type is `float32` and contains some floating numbers. What is the meaning of the numbers inside this array? How can I visualize them? I mean, I assumed that the result array will contain one of 4 class label (from 0 to 3) for every pixel, and then I will apply the color map for each class. In other words, the result should have been a prediction map, but I didn't get it. To understand better what I mean about prediction map, please visit the [Jeremy Jordan's blog about semantic segmentation](https://www.jeremyjordan.me/semantic-segmentation/).

```py
result = predictions[0]
plt.imshow(result)  # import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

3) What I finally want to do is like [Github: mrgloom - Semantic Segmentation Categorical Crossentropy Example](https://github.com/mrgloom/keras-semantic-segmentation-example/blob/master/multilabel_segmentation/categorical_crossentropy_example.py) did in `visualy_inspect_result` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Image input shape in your deep neural network architecture is (224,224,3), so width=height=224 and 3 color channels. And you need an additionnal dimension in case you want to give more than one image at a time to your model. So (1,224,224,3) or (something, 224,224,3).

**2)** According to the doc of [Segementation models repo](https://github.com/qubvel/segmentation_models/blob/master/docs/tutorial.rst), you can specify the number of classes you want as output `model = Unet('resnet34', classes=4, activation='softmax')`. Thus if you reshape your labelled image to have a shape (1,224,224,4). The last dimension is a mask channel indicating with a 0 or 1 if pixel i,j belongs to class k. Then you can predict and access to each output mask

```
masked = model.predict(np.array([im])[0]
mask_class0 = masked[:,:,0]
mask_class1 = masked[:,:,1]
```

**3)** Then using matplotlib you will be able to plot semantic segmentation or using [scikit-image](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.color.html) : `color.label2rgb` function

Comment: Thank you for the first answer. But I couldn't understand the second one. I uploaded the result image(224x224x3) of `model.predict()` [here](https://pasteboard.co/InDIukn.png). As you see there are two classes in the image, the circle ones and the road. But there is no clear distinction between these classes in terms of floating point numbers. I would like to understand which pixel belongs to which class.

Comment: I edited my answer accordingly. Please upvote and accept the answer and post a new question if you still encounter difficulties.

Comment: I am sorry but I can not upvote, here the stackoverflow's warning: "Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.".

I am still confused and did not solve the problem yet. What do you mean "Thus if you reshape **your labelled image** to have a shape (1,224,224,4)."? If you mean that the **labelled image** is `result` in my code which is the output of the `model.predict()` function, it can not be converted to (1,224,224,4) since its shape is (224x224x3).

Comment: As I said if you have 4 classes you should have a model that output of (1,224,224,4). The ouput are 0-1 mask. Mask0 correspond to class0 so if pixel i,j equals 1 it belongs to class0. And so on for every mask of the ouput

Comment: topic does not properly match the the asked question. Please modify that.